# How do I interpret this 10*10 confusion matrix?

Tags: python-3.x, confusion-matrix

I have below the confusion matrix with 10 Y categories. How do I calculate the accuracy for the categories A, D, and E, and find TP, TM, FP, FN for each?

```
    A    B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
   [41,  0,  0,  2,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  4],
   [ 1,  0,  0,  0,  4,  0,  0,  0,  0,  2],
   [ 3,  0, 12,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0, 51, 10,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 1,  0,  0,  3, 78,  0,  0,  0,  0,  5],
   [ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  3],
   [ 4,  0,  0,  0,  2,  0,  5,  0,  0,  4],
   [ 0,  0,  1,  1,  3,  0,  0,  2,  0,  1],
   [ 4,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [10,  0,  0,  5, 15,  0,  0,  0,  0, 24]
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Visualise your confusion matrix

```
X = [[41, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
 [3, 0, 12, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 51, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 3, 78, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
 [4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 5, 0, 0, 4],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1],
 [4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [10, 0, 0, 5, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 24]]

cm = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=list("ABCDEFGHIJ"), index=list("ABCDEFGHIJ")) 

print(cm)
```

Output:

```
    A  B   C   D   E  F  G  H  I   J
A  41  0   0   2   1  0  0  0  0   4
B   1  0   0   0   4  0  0  0  0   2
C   3  0  12   0   1  0  0  0  0   0
D   0  0   0  51  10  0  0  0  0   0
E   1  0   0   3  78  0  0  0  0   5
F   1  0   0   0   0  0  0  0  0   3
G   4  0   0   0   2  0  5  0  0   4
H   0  0   1   1   3  0  0  2  0   1
I   4  0   0   0   1  0  0  0  0   0
J  10  0   0   5  15  0  0  0  0  24
```

Reading a confusion matrix goes as the following: rows are actual labels, columns are predicted labels. A perfect model would have a **diagonal** confusion matrix, as it would correctly predict all the time! [Read more on confusion matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix).

Here, you can read that your model is sometimes wrong. It predicted `A` 10 times when the answer was actually `J`... But it's particularly good for category `G`: on the five times it was predicted, it was always right!

### Category accuracy

A category accuracy is obtained when counting how many times you predicted it well, among all the times you predicted it:

```
>>> cm["A"]["A"] / cm.sum(axis=0)["A"]                                                                                                               
0.6307692307692307

>>> cm["D"]["D"] / cm.sum(axis=0)["D"]                                                                                                               
0.8225806451612904

>>> cm["E"]["E"] / cm.sum(axis=0)["E"]                                                                                                               
0.6782608695652174
```

### TP, TN, FP, FN for each

These measures usually make sense in a binary classification setup, yet for a given category, you can imagine being in a one-vs-all (considered category vs all the rest) setup, which looks like binary, hence calculate these measures.

Taking advantage of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50666091/true-positive-rate-and-false-positive-rate-tpr-fpr-for-multi-class-data-in-py), you can get all TP, TN, FP, FN values for each category using the following:

```
FP = cm.sum(axis=0) - np.diag(cm)   
FN = cm.sum(axis=1) - np.diag(cm) 
TP = pd.Series(np.diag(cm), index=list("ABCDEFGHIJ"))
TN = np.matrix(cm).sum() - (FP + FN + TP)
```

Now, FP for category `A` is:

```
>>> FP["A"]
24  #  you can verify, it's the sum of all values except diagonal element
```

Same logic applies for all other measures.

Comment: Thank you @Arnaud, I will digest the content above!

Comment: I think the formula for TN should be TN = np.matrix(cm).sum() - (FP + FN + TP) :)

Comment: BTW, do you have any suggestions on how to evaluate the multilabel confusion matrix?

Comment: What do you mean by "evaluate"? To compute it? Based on predictions and ground truth? You could take advantage of sklearn yes: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answer, true positive and false positive and the other metrics only make sense in the context of binomial responses. This Wikipedia page outlines this in a little more detail:

[Precision and Recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall)

In the case above, you can't necessarily calculate an overall TP or FP rate, but you could calculate False 'A' and True 'A' and so on, as discussed in the answer above.