# Return tp, tn, fn, fp based on each input element

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I have a csv file with true and predicted labels (4 classes) associated with an ID. The csv file looks like this:

```
task_id,labels_true,labels_pred
76017-126511-18,2,2
76017-126512-18,0,3
76017-126513-18,2,2
76018-126511-18,2,2
76018-126512-18,2,2
76018-126513-18,2,1
76019-126511-18,2,2
76019-126512-18,1,0
```

I am using the confusion matrix from `sklearn.metrics`

```
y_true = df["labels_true"]
y_pred = df["labels_pred"]

cnf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels=[0,1,2,3])
```

It returns an array as follows:

```
[[ 554    1   28    0]
[  15  1375   43    0]
[  42   476 2263    0]
[   0    0    0    0]]
```

My aim is to return a list with each element ID associated with the respective tp, tn, fp, fn values like this:

```
task_id,labels_true,labels_pred, cm
76017-126511-18,2,2, tp 
76017-126513-18,2,2, tp
76018-126511-18,2,2, tp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: For multi-class cases, this is **not** possible.

---

As already suggested, the very notions of True Positives (TP), True Negatives (TN), False Positives (FP), and False Negatives (FN) come from binary classification settings; they can indeed be used in multi-class classification, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48100173/how-to-get-precision-recall-and-f-measure-from-confusion-matrix-in-python), but in such cases the notions are *not* a straightforward extension of the binary case, making what you ask here actually impossible.

In multi-class classification, all these notions are defined and calculated *per class*. And this renders any effort to uniquely identify a sample as being in one and only one of these categories (TP, FP, TN, FN) impossible.

Let's demonstrate this with some examples, using your case (4 classes `[0, 1, 2, 3]`).

Take a misclassified sample first, e.g.:

```
True label:      0
Predicted label: 3
```

- From the point of view (POV) of class `0`, this is a False Negative (FN): prediction is not `0`, as it should be
- From the POV of class `1`, this is a True Negative: it is *not* `1`, and it has *correctly* been classified as not `1`
- From the POV of class `2`, this is again a True Negative (TN): it is *not* `2`, and it has *correctly* been classified as not `2`
- From the POV of class `3`, this is a False Positive (FP): it has been wrongly classified as `3` without being so

Similar is the case for a correct classification, say

```
True label:      2
Predicted label: 2
```

- From the POV of class `0`, this is a True Negative (TN): it is *not* `0`, and it has *correctly* been classified as not `0`
- From the POV of class `1`, this is a True Negative (TN): it is *not* `1`, and it has *correctly* been classified as not `1`
- From the POV of class `2`, this is a True Positive (TP)
- From the POV of class `3`, this is a True Negative (TN): it is *not* `3`, and it has *correctly* been classified as not `3`

---

Given this exposition, it should hopefully be clear that what you ask is actually **not possible** in the multi-class case.

Answer (score 0):

It's a multi class confusion matrix. True/False positives are used for binary classification problems.
What you can do is to ecncode your labels as a binary values for example (classes 1,2,3 encoded as 1) and recalculate the confusion matrix.

Comment: But It's possibe to genereate tn, tp, fn, fp for multiple classes: see this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50666091/true-positive-rate-and-false-positive-rate-tpr-fpr-for-multi-class-data-in-py)