# Do accuracy_score (from Scikit-learn) compute overall accuracy or mean accuracy?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to clarify something about accuracy in Python. I have 3 classes of Cancer and I'm trying to predict samples (patients) by their condition. I have followed this method, proposed by a guy always from stack overflow :

[True Positive Rate and False Positive Rate (TPR, FPR) for Multi-Class Data in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50666091/true-positive-rate-and-false-positive-rate-tpr-fpr-for-multi-class-data-in-py)

Now I have done the exact same (only the part of sensitivity , specificity and accuracy were needed) :

```
 cnf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, pred_y)

 FP = cnf_matrix.sum(axis=0) - np.diag(cnf_matrix)  
 FN = cnf_matrix.sum(axis=1) - np.diag(cnf_matrix)
 TP = np.diag(cnf_matrix)
 TN = cnf_matrix.sum() - (FP + FN + TP)

 FP = FP.astype(float)
 FN = FN.astype(float)
 TP = TP.astype(float)
 TN = TN.astype(float)

 # Sensitivity, hit rate, recall, or true positive rate
 Sensitivity = TP/(TP+FN)
 # Specificity or true negative rate
 Specificity = TN/(TN+FP) 
 # Overall Accuracy (even if I dont think is overall)
 ACC = (TP+TN)/(TP+FP+FN+TN)
```

And as a result I get 3 lists (sensitivity, specificity and accuracy), but each of these lists contains 3 values ( I guess one per class ).

```
Sensitivity : [0.76999182 0.99404079 0.96377484]
Specificity : [0.98132687 0.97199254 0.9036957 ]
ACC         : [0.91487179 0.97717949 0.92794872]
```

But in the post the guy spoke about "overall accuracy", while instead I get the individual accuracy for each class (not bad tho). In fact when I use accuracy_score from Scikit-learn the final accuracy is different :

```
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test,pred_y)
accuracy:  0.9099999999999991
```

I assume that using the guy technique I get an accuracy for each class and so I can compute the **mean accuracy** (that in this case is 0.9399999999999992) while Scikit-learn gives me the **overall accuracy?** I think that it is important to know what is what, because sometimes the difference is about 20%, and is a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The accuracy returned from from [`sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html) is

```
(number of correctly predicted samples) / (total number of samples)
```

ie., accuracy.

What you're computing there is not accuracy for the entire dataset, it is the accuracy for the binary classification problem of each label, which you'll see listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_of_binary_classifiers) as accuracy for binary classification.

I haven't really ever seen that metric used, generally you'd pay attention to precision, recall, F1 score, and actual accuracy. Even if you **wanted** to use it, you should be careful when computing the mean: often there is a class imbalance in your data, so you might want to use a weighted mean.

Comment: The lists are the results from the computation of sensitivity, specificity and accuracy for each class using the confusion matrix. I did it by hand and the values are right. But for sure what you say seems right, I just did not get it completely (sorry). Are you saying that computing an overall accuracy is not possible and I should keep my 3 accuracy separated or vice versa, that computing for each class is dangerous and is better to just compute the accuracy with sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score ?